# How to bind data from database into tooltip of a chart point

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, mschart

I want to show some information from a database into tooltip onmouseover. How can I show the information from database into a tooltip of a chart?
the data will be based on the database table. 
I have tried to put the column name but it also produced an error. 
and I also have look at this site: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2008/11/11/microsoft-chart-control-how-to-using-keywords.aspx
there is no format to bind the data from database into tooltip.
I just wondering is it possible to do it?

Here is the that I have tried:

```
<asp:Series ChartType="Line" Name="Series1" Legend="Legend1" LegendText="colummn1" ToolTip="Value of X: #VALY Value of Y #VALY">
            </asp:Series>
```

it show x and y value...

I also have tried to put the code inside the chart,

```
Chart1.Series("Series1").ToolTip = "Tooltip: #column1"
```

it only display 'Tooltip: #column1'... not the value of column1....

Some Code:

```
    Protected Sub Chart1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Chart1.Load
    Dim sqlProducts As String = "Select P, R, L, Column1 from tbl_Name"
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlProducts, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, "tbl_name")

    Dim ChartArea1 As ChartArea = New ChartArea()
    Dim Legend1 As Legend = New Legend()
    Dim Series1 As Series = New Series()

    Series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
    Series1.Legend = "Legend1"
    Chart1.TabIndex = 0
    Chart1.Series("Series1").XValueMember = "L"
    Chart1.Series("Series1").YValueMembers = "P"
    Chart1.Series("Series2").YValueMembers = "R"
    Chart1.Series("Series1").ToolTip = "Tooltip: " + "Column1"
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = "10"
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = "7"
    Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("tbl_name")
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this

```
Chart1.Series("Series1").ToolTip = "Tooltip: " + <Value From DB as string>;
```

Otherwise, following will show your points (x, y) in when you hover over a point in your chart.

```
Chart1.Series("Series1").ToolTip =  "Value of X: #VALY Value of Y #VALY";
```

**UPDATE**

Now that you've given the code behind it's easy to answer your question :)
Do it like this

```
Chart1.Series("Series1").ToolTip = "Tooltip: " + ds.Tables("tbl_name").Rows(1).Column1.ToString()
```

This will only show the Column1 value of the first row

Comment: should I add another sql syntax at <Value From DB as string> or I just take it from the sql column that I have already called, from example: I already call an sql syntax select column1, column2, column 3, and I want to add column3 on the tooltip...

Comment: Yes you should replace "<Value From DB as string>" with your DB column value :)

Comment: I already tried the second suggestion and it works,,,, but that is not what I want... I want it to display information from another column,,, see the edit code above...

Comment: See my updated answer. You should learn how to get values from your dataset. Read bit on the topic. You can't just say "Column1". Compiler doesn't know that you are referring to a column. It's just a string for the compiler. You should follow ADO.Net syntaxt to retreive values. Above example shows how to retreive values from row 1. If you need to show all values you'll have to loop through your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sam...
may I ask, there is no Rows(1).Column1 showing up? it only pop up getcolumnerror, etc.

Comment: Do you get Rows(1).Items ?

Comment: Ok then type ds.Tables("tbl_name").Rows(1).Item("Column1")

Comment: yeah... It works... now I need to loop it through all the data and modified it a bit... Thanks for the suggestion...

Comment: Yup. Pleasure! Have fun with it :)